# Como criar funções disponível globalmente no laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Gostaria de criar funções que esteja disponível globalmente para reutilizar o código.

Qual seria o melhor jeito de fazer isso, no laravel...

O fluxo que preciso seria assim.:

Vou receber uma requisição " Rota "

> depois vou processar > " Controler " nesse caso terei que fazer varios processamento sendo assim pensei em fazer varias funções que possa ser utilizada, tem caso que vou utilizar API de terceiros para o processamento também.
>   depois vou passar exibir usando > " View Blade".

Qualquer ideia será bem vinda...

Comment: Não sei se o Laravel tem algo já pra isso, mas sugiro colocar essas funções separada num arquivo e usar um namespace nesse arquivo, daí pode usar algo como `MyUtils\myFunction()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você procura provavelmente é uma classe de Auxilo, uma classe Helper.

**1** - Crie um arquivo no caminho /App/Helpers/Helper.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper
{
    public static function shout(string $string)
    {
        return strtoupper($string);
    }
}
```

**2** - Adicione um apelido, Alias, no arquivo config/app.php

```
<?php

'aliases' => [
 ...
    'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,
 ...
```

**3** - Uso nas views

```
{!! Helper::shout('exemplo de uso de helper!!') !!}
```

**4** - Use em qualquer controlador ou outros lugares:

```
<?php // Code within app/Http/Controllers/SomeController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Helper;

    class SomeController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            Helper::shout('now i\'m using my helper class in a controller!!');
        }
        ...
```

[Fonte em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5)